# php server can't connect to the remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, mysql-connection

We have two servers.

server 1 and server 2

they are running with Directadmin / CentOS6

my plan:

- server 1 is running php and html, images...etc.
- server 2 is running mysql and phpmyadmin

They are all set up using directadmin.

mysql on server 2 is listening on port 4415 and I enabled 4415 port in server 1 and server 2 firewall.

Testing :

1. created a database on server 2 and "Access Hosts" on directadmin
2. I uploaded a php-file to server 1 to connect mysql(server2).

It was very very slow and I got this error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '123.123.123.123' (4)

When I connect to mysql(server2) from "mysql workbench" (my pc) it is very fast and works!

how can I do? I've tested all the way.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you already check mysql server error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add user in mysql in this way:

```
user@server1
```

This is the way MySQL expect to have user records for remove connection. And permit this user to manage database you use in php application.

User is created in MySQL with command:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'server1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

And you grant privileges to the user with command like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'server1';
```

where 'database' is the name of your database

Comment: Thanks, but I created a user on server1 same name and password as server 2 account. but still not work

Comment: This user (as described above is created in database, not in OS. Check my edited answer for command

Comment: I got your mean . But still error(4)

Comment: Did you set explicitly in your code to connect to this port (4415)?

Comment: netstat port listen is show 4415. and  my php testing code is  : mysql_connect("123.123.123.123:4415","user","password","UTF8") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I using mysql workbench(my pc) connect mysql is work. So....maybe server 1 problem (php remote mysql setting?) ???

Comment: You should use user@server1, not only user

Comment: Thansk, I had test : mysql_connect("123.123.123.123:4415","username@123.123.123.123","password","UTF8").  still show :  Can't connect to MySQL server on '123.123.123.123' (4)

Comment: One strange idea: check if you have selinux run, stop it and try again

Comment: At the first time, we had check it. haven't selinux.
But, we have cloudlinux and su php.This matter?

Comment: As commented above check mysql logs please

Comment: oh...Thank you for reminding me to check the mysql log. I go check it later thanks very much Romeo